# Error 2019 when trying to build in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, db2

Someone wrote a program a few years ago and I have to modify it. While trying to build the code using .NET 4.5 the message:

```
Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 
'Edm.DateTime[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member 
'SRVC_EVNT_END_TM' in type 'SimModel.STR_SRVC_EVNT' is not compatible with 
'DB2.time[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member 
'SRVC_EVNT_END_TM' in type 'SimModel.Store.STR_SRVC_EVNT'. 
C:\Users\ponthcm\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Applications\SIM.Entity\SimModel.edmx 5299 13 SIM.Entity
```

I talked to the programmer that wrote it and the only difference we could come up with while setting up the project is it was using Entity Framework 4 and I have Entity Framework 5 currently.

Besides that the only other possible problem I can see is that it is trying to put `DateTime` into `Time` because of the size difference. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give us more details ? Where is this error thrown, what are you trying to do ? ..

Comment: Currently I am just trying to build it. Read from database and populate  tables for a website with the data. I believe he made this project Model first. The error sends you to SimModel.edmx which just has all the tables the other guy made.

Comment: This is a .NET (4.0) ASP site using EF on DB2.  There are 100 errors during compile and all are the same - that the .NET DateTime type is not compatible with the DB2.Time type.  I understand they are different sizes... but at one point this apparently worked just fine and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the IBM Dataserver Client addin for VS2010 was Version 10.5 and the code was written in Version 9.5. After the addin was uninstalled and installed using 9.5 the errors went away.